# Слишком мало аргументов для вызова

Tags: c++, c

Только начал писать программу, и уже застрял. В 17 строке (5 снизу)

```
scanf_s("%s", A.message);
```

> ошибка: слишком мало аргументов для вызова

Если вместо scanf_s заюзать gets_s, то прога запускается, но не работает, и в 
warning такое: "передано недостаточно аргументов для строки формата"
Искал в интернете, так и не получилось пофиксить. Вроде бы всё правильно, я 
даже нашел похожую прогу в инете, там такая же ошибка, хотя та прога должна 
работать, потому что она написана в "Примерах" в обучающей статье.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Mine
{
    int key[50];
    char message[500];
};

int main()
{
    struct Mine A;
    system("chcp 1251");
    printf("Введіть ключ - ");
    scanf_s("%d", &A.key);
    printf("\nВведіть повідомлення - ");
    //scanf_s("%s", A[30].message);
    gets_s(A[30].message);
    printf("\nВи ввели: %d, %s", A.key, A.message);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: У вас все задом наперед описано. Это именно для `scanf_s` вы получаете "передано недостаточно аргументов для строки формата". А для `gets_s` - "слишком мало аргументов для вызова".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> scanf_s("%s", A[30].message);
> ```

```
scanf_s("%s", A.message, 500);
```

> ```
> gets_s(A[30].message);
> ```

```
gets_s(A.message);
```

Comment: А что это за ошибка? https://i.imgur.com/SoBmmQQ.jpg

Comment: @Asmund, пишешь куда-то за пределами переменной `A`.

Comment: @Asmund, если помогло, то надо принять ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: Должно быть `500`, а не `499`.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, нет 499. 500 - общая длина и 1 символ на `\0`.

Comment: Почитайте ссылку из моего ответа на справку. Передаётся именно размер буфера, а кол-во возможных символов (которое без учёта терминирующего нуля), если хочется, передаётся в форматной строке. Типа `"%499s"`.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, а нет, ты прав, 500. Не так [их фразу](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2017) _"char s[10];
scanf_s("%9s", s, (unsigned)_countof(s)); // buffer size is 10, width specification is 9"_ понял. Кстати, а зачем одновременно и размер, и спецификатор ширины - так и надо делать или просто так написали?

Comment: Одновременно вряд ли имеет смысл, может только для какого-то обобщённого кода, чтобы строку формата подставлять и в версию без `_s` суффикса. Отдельным параметром передавать удобнее, чем в составе строки. Иначе нужно [извращаться](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1621394/3240681).

Answer (score 2):

В [справке по функции](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2017) сказано:

> Unlike `scanf` and `wscanf`, `scanf_s` and `wscanf_s` require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type `c`, `C`, `s`, `S`, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.

Т.е. для любых параметров перечисленных типов требуется указывать в паре (сразу за указателем на буфер) размер приёмного буфера, чтобы исключить возможное переполнение, если входная строка вдруг окажется слишком длинной. Т.о. вызов функции должен выглядеть так:

```
scanf_s("%s", A.message, 500);
```

Когда используется массив, можно `500` заменить на макрос [`_countof`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/countof-macro?view=vs-2017), дополнительно выполнив приведение к `unsigned` типу. Об этом сказано в примечании:

> The size parameter is of type `unsigned`, not `size_t`. Use a static cast to convert a `size_t` value to unsigned for 64-bit build configurations.

Получится такой вызов:

```
scanf_s("%s", A.message, (unsigned)_countof(A.message));
```